# C++ : Connecting a member of a class to its definition

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, I have more experience in OCaml and Python. I want to learn C++ by making a program playing "Morpion Solitaire". My beginnings are a bit difficult.

In the following code :

```
typedef enum {NORTH, NORTHEAST, EAST, SOUTHEAST} direction;

char deltax[4] = { 0, 1, 1, 1};
char deltay[4] = { 1, 1, 0, -1};

class Coords {
 private:
  char x,y;

 public:
  Coords(char xx,char yy){
    x = xx;
    y = yy;
  };

  char get_x() const { return x;}

  char get_y() const { return y;}
};

class Line {
 private:
  Coords orig;
  direction dir;
  Coords newcross;

 public:
  Line(char x1, char y1, direction d, char x2, char y2) {
    orig = Coords(x1,y1);
    dir = d;
    newcross = Coords(x2,y2);
  };

  Coords nthpoint(char n) {
    char x,y;

    x = orig.get_x() + n*deltax[dir];
    y = orig.get_y() + n*deltay[dir];

    return Coords(x,y);
  };
};
```

the compiler tells me this :

```
nico@gaston:~/Travail/Cplusplus/morpion++$ g++ -c morpion.cc 
morpion.cc: In constructor ‘Line::Line(char, char, direction, char, char)’:
morpion.cc:29:57: error: no matching function for call to ‘Coords::Coords()’
   Line(char x1, char y1, direction d, char x2, char y2) {
                                                         ^
morpion.cc:29:57: note: candidates are:
morpion.cc:11:3: note: Coords::Coords(char, char)
   Coords(char xx,char yy){
   ^
morpion.cc:11:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
morpion.cc:6:7: note: Coords::Coords(const Coords&)
```

I don't understand the message. I have given a 2 argument constructor for class `Coords`, but the compiler keeps telling me that `orig = Coords(x1,y1)` calls the constructor with 0 arguments.

What did I miss ?

Remark : I initially put the declarations of Coords and Line in different files, and thought I did not use the proper `#include`, but putting everything in one single file didn't solve the problem...

Comment: The compiler doesn't point to `orig = Coords(x1,y1)` (which is an assignment and not an initialisation, by the way) but to the space between the parameter list and the function body. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is the list of recommended books.

Comment: Prefer initializer lists to assignments in the constructor's body. Also prefer C++11 member initialization and uniform initialization.

Answer (score 6):

```
Line(char x1, char y1, direction d, char x2, char y2)
  : orig(x1,y1), dir(d), newcross(x2, y2) {}
```

`Coords` doesn't have a default constructor. Your original code attempts to first default-construct `orig`, then assign a new value to it. But for lack of that default constructor, the first step fails.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you are having is that all class members and basses must be constructed before entering the constructor body.  Because of that what your constructor actually looks like after having the implicit constructions added by the compiler is

```
Line(char x1, char y1, direction d, char x2, char y2): orig(), dir(), newcross() {
    orig = Coords(x1,y1); // this is assignment not construction
    dir = d; // this is assignment not construction
    newcross = Coords(x2,y2); // this is assignment not construction
};
```

This is not a problem for `dir` since it can be implicitly constructed but `Coords` is not so `orig()` and `newcross()` fails.

To fix this you need to use the member initialization list and have a constructor like

```
Line(char x1, char y1, direction d, char x2, char y2) : orig(x1, y1), newcross(x2, y2), dir(d) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: the fix:

```
Line(char x1, char y1, direction d, char x2, char y2) :
    orig(x1, y1), newcross(x2, y2), dir(d)
{
};
```

The constructor of class `Line` is to call constructors of all members of this class, and does this prior to the execution of constructor body. That is, the member `orig` should be constructed before line

```
orig = Coords(x1,y1);
```

execution. By default, the default constructor is called, but in your case the class `Coords` has no default constructor. When we write `orig(x1, y1)`, we override the default, and the constructor `Coords(x1, y1)` is called to construct `orig`.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. So fast !!! :-)
I saw this syntax in the C++ book from Stroustrup, didn't understand it at the moment.
I'm releived :-P

Comment: Downvoter, care to reverse after the edit? This is fine now.

Comment: BTW the initialization list should be in the order of declaration, else compiler will moan. That is, `orig(...), dir(...), newcross(...)`, not `orig(...), newcross(...), dir(...)`.